# Rails asset not precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

A page is returning the error `AssetNotPrecompiled`on a page in a Rails 6.0.3 application.

The layout attempts to initialise css variables in a first file, then load the bulk of css classes and finally some overriding of the bulk classes, personalised to the invoked controller.  This layout thus defines

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'terl/initialise', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'terl/personalise', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

The error is firing on the invocation of `terl/initialise` line.
*the directory structur for files is desired to maintain sanity over multiple personalisation cases*

`stylesheets/application.css` has no  `*= require`  statement for the initialise and personalise files.  Thus, `config/initializers/assets.rb` requires setting for precompilation:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( appinit.css, zzpersonalised.css, terl/initialise.css, terl/personalise.css )
```

the former two doing the initialisation and personalisation for the regular `application.html.erb` layout.

Where is the syntax mistaken?

Comment: remove those commas, spaces are the separators: `%w(appinit.css zzpersonalised.css terl/initialise.css terl/personalise.css)`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the old syntax of declaring an array resolves the matter

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [ 'appinit.css', 'zzpersonalised.css', 'terl/initialise.css', 'terl/personalise.css' )
```